# I cannot free up empty space for the root partition: how can I add some space?

Tags: root, resize

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and I want to free up some space in my root directory, which is overloaded. I especially want to change the path used for installing applications (they are getting installed directly to the root drive).

When I searched about this problem and it showed some terminal commands I am not familiar with or how I deal with it.

[image: Gnome Disk screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You are advised not to pursue your ambition to change the path where applications are installed. Software packages are prepared to install files in specific locations, so to really change that, you would need to repackage all the software before installing it. What can be done is to redirect the storage of a specific path to another storage volume (partition).

15 GB is not a lot, but still can be enough for a root partition if you are a little carefull. Some interventions to free disk space on the root partition are

- Remove old kernels. You only need the current kernel and the previous one. Each older kernel takes an additional 400 - 500 MB.
- Perform an `sudo apt clean` to free some space by removing cached downloaded `.deb` files.
- Prefer `.deb` versions of software. Containerized applications like snaps typically need significant more disk space.

That could be enough to maintain a safe amount of free space (about 1 GB).

If this is not enough:

- You can clean the log and limit their size,  to reduce the log file sizes, are provider here.
- You could redirect your `/tmp` and `/var/tmp` to another storage volume (symbolic links or mount-binding)
- You could redirect your `/snap` directory to another storage volume. On a default install, that directory already takes 5 GB.

Comment: as you see i have 50 gb free space can i move the ntfs patition alittle bit to empty some space